# How to write a query to download data from DBLP?

Tags: parsing, data-mining, data-extraction, data-processing, citations

I want to download DBLP dataset, which consists of bibliographic data in computer science. 
I want to select a list of conferences from two research areas i.e., computer security (ISI, NDSS, ARES, ACSAC FC, and SP) and information retrieval (AIRS, CIKM, SIGIR, JCDL, ICTIR, ECIR, TREC, and WSDM).
Although DBLP dataset is available on https://aminer.org/citation (V4), I want to avoid parsing by using query as we use on Web of Science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the DBLP XML dump from https://dblp.org/faq/1474679.html

This is the recommended way to extract larger parts from DBLP. You can easily get per-author bibliographies, but not entire conference series, except by using this.

Then 3xyradt whatever parts you want to use.